# How to hide the linker warning start with AL (ALINK)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I got this warning while compiling the VC++ project.

`1>ALINK : warning AL1073: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor`

I think it is safe to hide this in my situation (concluded). How to ignore the linking ALINK errors.

`/ignore:1073` or `/ignore:AL1073` doesn't work. It gives me this error

`1>LINK : fatal error LNK1147: invalid number specified with option '/ignore:1073'`